# (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Tags: node.js, postgresql, memory-leaks, connection, node-postgres

I am using pg node module for connecting database. I have been creating multiple connection for each DML operation. when continuous query execution takes place
I got  warning message as "(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit." The given pg defaults poolSize is 5.

```
 var pg = require('pg')
 pg.defaults.poolSize = 5;
 var dbHelper = {
 initializeConnection: function (callback) {
    pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            done(client);
            return callback(err, null);
        }
        callback(null, client, done);
    });

    pg.on('error', function (err) {
    });
    pg.end();
},
  query: function (pgQuery, args, callback, options) {
    this.initializeConnection(function (err, client, done) {
           client.query(pgQuery, args, function (err, response) {
            done();
            return callback(err, response);
        });
    });
},
};

 module.exports = dbHelper;
```

sample Query

```
 dbHelper.query("SELECT name,age,address FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE id=$1", [1001], function (err, response) {
        callback(err, response);
    });
```

how to prevent the Event emitter memory leek.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you do not release the connection properly:

```
pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
      if (err) {
          done(client);
          return callback(err, null);
      }
      callback(null, client, done);
  });
```

this should be:

```
pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
    if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
    } else {
        callback(null, client);
        done();
    }
});
```

i.e. you call `done()` when there was no error.

And if you want to avoid this kind of errors altogether - check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) ;)